# Jquery code not working till refresh

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have two html pages (index.html and game.html) the second page (game.html) contains a html code that it will be filled using js code .

Firstly, when I open index.html there is no error when I move to game.html I get this error in my console :

```
 tag does not match. Expected: </ meta>  game.html: 16: 7
```

and when I return to index.html I get this error in my console :

```
 tag does not match. Expected: </ meta>  index.html: 16: 7
```

My problem is when I move to game.html the js code doesn't work and after I refresh my page every thing works fine and the page is filled

#### Note :

when I start my app with game.html every thing works fine.
My problem starts If I start my app with index.html and then move to game.html page

#### I tried to :

1- close meta tags like this

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

the error above disappear but js code doesn't work until I  refresh my page

2- remove JS code from game.html
but the error still persist

3- change the content of QCM.js file that I was working on but the problem still persist (to be sure that there is no javascript errors)

this is index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" type="text/css" />       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.css" />      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />    
        
        
        <title> sounds </title>
    </head>
    <body dir="rtl" lang='ar' class="contentBack">
        
        
        
    <div data-role="page" id="homefa" data-theme="a" >
    
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        
        
        <h1 id="TitleHeader" style=""> sounds </h1>
        
        </div>
    

        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="outer" style="">
                <div class="menu_simple" align="center" style="">

                    <ul>

                    <li><a data-transition="slidedown"  style="font-family:mySecondFont;text-align:center;" href="game.html"> Start game </a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>  
        
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is game.html (the error still persist even after removing body content) :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
            <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
            <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" type="text/css" />   
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.css" />      
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />    
            
            
            <title> sounds </title>
        </head>
        <body dir="rtl" lang='ar' class="contentBack" >
            
            
            
        <div data-role="page" id="gameTT" data-theme="a" >
        
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <a style="margin-top:13px;margin-left:10px;color:white;" href="#"  data-rel="back" >رجوع</a>
            <h1 id="TitleHeader" style="" > sounds </h1>
            
            </div>
        
    
        <div data-role="content">
                <div align="center" >
                
                    <h1 id="QuestNum" style="font-family:mySecondFont;text-align:center;"> </h1>
                    
                    <div id="soundDIV">
                    <input type="image" id="pauseMp3"    class="inline "  src="img/pause.png" alt="click" height="65"  width="65"/>
                    <input id="playMp3"  type="image"   class="inline "  src="img/play.png" alt="click" height="65"  width="65"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <br/><br/>
                
                <div class="section group" >
                
                    
                
                    <div id="col0" style="text-align:center;" class="col span_1_of_3">
                    
                    
                    </div>
                    <div id="col1" style="text-align:center;" class="col span_1_of_3">
                    
                    
                    
                    </div>
                    <div id="col2" style="text-align:center;" class="col span_1_of_3">
                    
                    
                    
                    </div>
                    
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="section group" >
                <ul id="choice-block">
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                </ul>
                
                </div>
                
                <div id="Why"></div>
                
    
            
            <div id="frame" >
            
            
            </div>
            
            
        </div>  
        </div>
        
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sounds.js" ></script>
            
        
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
            
            <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/QCM.js" ></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
            
            
            
        </body>
        
        
        
    

</html>
```

the QCM.js file is like this

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
    
    // for example to add a button to game.html 

$(document.createElement('div')).addClass('choice-box').attr('id', 'submitbutton').text('check').appendTo('#frame');

    
    
    });
```

Comment: `a html code that it will be filled using js code` How that?

Comment: using jQuery appendTo() Method

Comment: I guess your issue comes from here. Can you post this specific relevant code?

Comment: yes I will do. but when I start my app with game.html every thing works fine 
the problem when I move from page to page

Comment: Sorry, i don't see any error in your posted code

Comment: I think the source of problem is JQUERY mobile

Comment: I think you are right. I'm not a jQuery mobile user so i cannot really help you on it. But if you provide online sample replicating your issue, i guess someone could help you